# Extract multiple string elements in table column using Impala or Hive

Tags: sql, hive, impala, hue

I have a column A which elements consist of lists with multiple **string** elements (not arrays), such as:

```
   **A**
1 'A123','B234','C123'
2 'A123','B234'
3 'A124',
```

The amount of list elements varies across records. The list elements however are always of the same length and are separated by comma.

I need to extract these string elements to a separate table/list B and get the distinct elements such as:

```
  **B**
1 'A123'
2 'A124'
3 'B234'
4 'C123'
```

How can I do that using SQL? I'm using Impala or Hive
I'm using Cloudera Hue for analysis.

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `lateral view explode` to create a column with array elements, then dictinct, e.g.

```
SELECT distinct elem  as col1
  FROM tableA LATERAL VIEW explode(split(array_column, ',')) aTable AS elem
```

See [Hive's manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) for more details on `lateral view`

Comment: No need for parens around `elem`.  `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your answer does not work in my case because my column is a string value (I guess). I get following error message: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter

Comment: @KostaS. I suppose your elements are separated by comma. In that case you need to split the string, then do explode. I've edited the answer.